# Change speficic height of grid element html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm new in Frontend development, I'm doing a "resume website".
I have two columns and 2 rows, I'm using grid containers.

As you can see on the screenshot my second column has the same height as the first while I would like it to be "sensitive". (Suppress all that empty space while the second block under it comes closer). Sorry for my English. I will add my code under the screenshot.

[Results of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piBPE.png)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var css = document.createElement('link'); css.href = 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css'; css.rel = 'stylesheet'; css.type = 'text/css'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css); })(); </script>

     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">   
    <meta name="description" content="Resume Maria Macarena ">
    <meta name="author" content="Pierre ">

    <title>Resume Macarena </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Normalize.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="essai.css">

</head>

    <body>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <aside class="grid-item aside">
                <div class="container photo">
                    <img src="Maca_profil.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                    <div class="bottom-left">Macarena </div>       
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i> Lawyer</li>
                        <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Las Condes, Santiago, Chile</li>
                        <li><i class="fas fa-at"></i> <a href="mailto:#"> Email: </a></li>
                        <li><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> +********</li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2><i class="fas fa-asterisk"></i> Skills</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Microsoft Excel
                                <div class="container progressBar">
                                <div class="skills excel">80%</div>
                                </div></li>
                            <li>Microsoft Word
                                <div class="container progressBar">
                                <div class="skills word">100%</div>
                                </div></li>
                            <li>Etc..</li>
                        </ul>
                    <h2><i class="fas fa-asterisk"></i> Languages</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Español
                            <div class="container progressBar">
                                <div class="skills spanish">100%</div>
                                </div></li>
                            <li>English
                            <div class="container progressBar">
                                <div class="skills english">80%</div>
                                </div></li>
                            <li>Français
                            <div class="container progressBar">
                                <div class="skills french">20%</div>
                                </div></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

            </aside>
            <section class="grid-item item2">
                <div class="contenu">
                <h2><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i> WORK EXPERIENCE</h2>
                    <h3>EY Consulting</h3><p> <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> November 2014 – March 2017</p>
                    <ul>
                           <li><span class="souligne">Position</span>: Senior lawyer at the Santiago business tax advisory group.</li> 
                            <li><span class="souligne">Relevant duties</span>: compilation, study and processing of relevant information on the specific business line of the client. Research and draft memorandums concerning the design of efficient tax structures for multinational clients. Involved in complex repatriation cases before Chilean Tax Authorities. Planning and implementation of corporate restructuring.</li> 
                        </ul>
                <hr>
                    <h3>Chilean Judicial Assistance Corporation</h3>
                       <p><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> November 2013 – May 2014</p> 
                        <ul>
                            <li><span class="souligne">Position</span>: Compulsory Government Internship</li> 
                            <li><span class="souligne">Relevant duties</span>: disposal of judicial and extrajudicial civil cases</li> 
                        </ul>
                <hr>
                    <h3>Bordachar, Alvear, Meneses, Montes y Cía.</h3>
                    <p><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> March 2012 – August 2012</p>
                        <ul>
                           <li><span class="souligne">Position</span>: Corporate Law Clerk</li> 
                            <li><span class="souligne">Relevant duties</span>: legal services to Chilean and foreign clients undertaking business in Chile.</li> 
                        </ul> 
                    </div>

            </section>
            <div class="grid-item item3">
                <h2><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> ACADEMIC BACKGROUND</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h5>Pontifical Catholic University of Chile</h5>
                            <h6><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 2015 </h6> 
                            <p>Advanced diploma “Litigation and New Procedures”</p> </li><hr>
                        <li><h5>Arbitration Academy (Paris, France)</h5>
                            <h6><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 2012 </h6>
                           <p>Diploma "International Academy for Arbitration Law"</p><hr></li>
                        <li><h5>Catholic University of Chile</h5>
                            <h6><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 2008 – 2012</h6><p>Bachelor of Laws, Pontifical</p> <hr></li>
                        <li><h5>High and Elementary School, Sagrado Corazón de Apoquindo</h5>
                            <h6><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 1998 – 2007</h6></li>
                    </ul>     

            </div>

        </div>
        <footer class="container footer">
            <div class="row">


            </div>
        </footer> 
    </body>




    * {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    }


    .grid-container {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: darkgrey;
    }
    /* ASIDE */

    .aside {

        margin: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
        background-color: #E0E2E3;
        opacity: .9;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }
    .photo {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative; 
      text-align: center;
      color: #282828;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    /* Bottom left text */
    .bottom-left {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      left: 10px;
      font-weight: 600; 
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 15px;
      padding: 0px;
      line-height: 25px;
      padding-bottom: auto;
    }

    i {
        color: #1689AC;
    }

    /* BODY */

    .aside, .item2, .item3 {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    h2, h3 {
        margin-left: 15px;

    }

    h2 {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }


    p {
        margin-top: -15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }


    .item2 {
        background-color: #E0E2E3;
        opacity: .9;
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }

    .item3 {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        background-color: #E0E2E3;
        opacity: .9;
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }

    .item3 h5, h6, p {
        line-height: 20px;  
    }

    .item3 h5 {
        font-size: 1em;
        display: inline;
    }
    .item3 h6 {
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-size: .9em;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;;
    }
    .item3 p {

        margin-top: auto;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    /* PROGRESS BARS */

    .progressBar {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: #9DA3A4;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .skills {
      height: inherit;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 5px;
      font-size: .7em;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .excel {width: 80%; background-color: #1689AC;}
    .word {width: 100%;background-color: #1689AC;}
    .spanish {width: 100%; background-color: #1689AC;}
    .english {width: 80%; background-color: #1689AC;}
    .french {width: 20%; background-color: #1689AC;}
    /* FOOTER */

    .footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: ;
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 35% 65% ;
    }
    .item2, .item3 {
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 5px;


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your "items" inside one grid container.

```html
<section class="grid-item">
   <div class="item2">...WORK EXPERIENCE</div>
   <div class="item3">...ACADEMIC BACKGROUND</div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zq1g7nh6/

Comment: It was so simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define 2 columns in a row and in the second column, there should be mulitiple rows. for example (basic structure):

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class="col"> some content </div>
   <div class="col">
      <div class="row"> some content</div>
      <div class="row"> some content</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
    * {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    }


    .grid-container {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: darkgrey;
    }
    /* ASIDE */

    .aside {

        margin: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
        background-color: #E0E2E3;
        opacity: .9;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }
    .photo {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative; 
      text-align: center;
      color: #282828;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    /* Bottom left text */
    .bottom-left {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      left: 10px;
      font-weight: 600; 
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 15px;
      padding: 0px;
      line-height: 25px;
      padding-bottom: auto;
    }

    i {
        color: #1689AC;
    }

    /* BODY */

    .aside, .item2, .item3 {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    h2, h3 {
        margin-left: 15px;

    }

    h2 {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }


    p {
        margin-top: -15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }


    .item2 {
        background-color: #E0E2E3;
        opacity: .9;
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }

    .item3 {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        background-color: #E0E2E3;
        opacity: .9;
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }

    .item3 h5, h6, p {
        line-height: 20px;  
    }

    .item3 h5 {
        font-size: 1em;
        display: inline;
    }
    .item3 h6 {
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-size: .9em;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;;
    }
    .item3 p {

        margin-top: auto;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    /* PROGRESS BARS */

    .progressBar {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: #9DA3A4;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .skills {
      height: inherit;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 5px;
      font-size: .7em;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .excel {width: 80%; background-color: #1689AC;}
    .word {width: 100%;background-color: #1689AC;}
    .spanish {width: 100%; background-color: #1689AC;}
    .english {width: 80%; background-color: #1689AC;}
    .french {width: 20%; background-color: #1689AC;}
    /* FOOTER */

    .footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: ;
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 35% 65% ;
    }
    .item2, .item3 {
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 5px;


    }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="grid-container">
    <aside class="grid-item aside">
      <div class="container photo">
        <img src="Maca_profil.jpg" alt="profile picture">
        <div class="bottom-left">Macarena </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i> Lawyer</li>
          <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Las Condes, Santiago, Chile</li>
          <li><i class="fas fa-at"></i> <a href="mailto:#"> Email: </a></li>
          <li><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> +********</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <h2><i class="fas fa-asterisk"></i> Skills</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Microsoft Excel
            <div class="container progressBar">
              <div class="skills excel">80%</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>Microsoft Word
            <div class="container progressBar">
              <div class="skills word">100%</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>Etc..</li>
        </ul>
        <h2><i class="fas fa-asterisk"></i> Languages</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Español
            <div class="container progressBar">
              <div class="skills spanish">100%</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>English
            <div class="container progressBar">
              <div class="skills english">80%</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>Français
            <div class="container progressBar">
              <div class="skills french">20%</div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <section class="grid-item">
      <div class="item2">
        <div class="contenu">
        <h2><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i> WORK EXPERIENCE</h2>
        <h3>EY Consulting</h3>
        <p> <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> November 2014 – March 2017</p>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="souligne">Position</span>: Senior lawyer at the Santiago business tax advisory group.</li>
          <li><span class="souligne">Relevant duties</span>: compilation, study and processing of relevant information on the specific business line of the client. Research and draft memorandums concerning the design of efficient tax structures for multinational clients. Involved in complex repatriation cases before Chilean Tax Authorities. Planning and implementation of corporate restructuring.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item3">
        <h2><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> ACADEMIC BACKGROUND</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h5>Pontifical Catholic University of Chile</h5>
            <h6><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 2015 </h6>
            <p>Advanced diploma “Litigation and New Procedures”</p>
          </li>
          <hr>
          <li>
            <h5>Arbitration Academy (Paris, France)</h5>
            <h6><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 2012 </h6>
            <p>Diploma "International Academy for Arbitration Law"</p>
            <hr>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h5>Catholic University of Chile</h5>
            <h6><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 2008 – 2012</h6>
            <p>Bachelor of Laws, Pontifical</p>
            <hr>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h5>High and Elementary School, Sagrado Corazón de Apoquindo</h5>
            <h6><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 1998 – 2007</h6>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>

  </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="container footer">
    <div class="row">


    </div>
  </footer>
```